# delete pixel from the raster image with specific range value

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, gdal

**update :**
any idea how to delete pixel from specific range value raster image with 
using `numpy/scipy` or `gdal`?

**or how to can create new raster with some class using raster calculation expressions**(better)

for example i have a raster image with the 
5 class :

```
1. 0-100 
2. 100-200 
3. 200-300 
4. 300-500 
5. 500-1000
```

and i want to delete class 1 range value 
or maybe class `1,2,4,5`

i begin with this script :

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open("raster3.tif")
myarray = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
#print myarray.shape
#print myarray.size
#print myarray
new=np.delete(myarray[::2], 1)
```

but i cant to complete

the image
[White in class 5 and black class 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4bk4.jpg)

Comment: Well... that image-upload failed, as it's now a jpeg. When you upload it correctly, also add some more information on what you want to achieve exactly. Do you want to delete some pixels according to value within some class (like remove 0-100 in black?) And what does delete mean? Replacing with 0? If it's a raster-image, there should probably a valid-value for each pixel within some page+series.

Comment: i want to delete some class with all pixel within the class,i dont want replace with 0 that is wrong

Comment: Okay. I think i can't wait for that image today. Have a look [at this](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.external.tifffile.html#imread). It sounds very easy using this high-quality library (it's based on numpy and scipy and should be easy to install if these two prereqs are already installed). The simple approach: read in the image (need to select which pages/series to read) and remove the dimension you want to delete (everything is based on numpy-array in skimage). Good luck.

Comment: You can't *"delete"* a pixel from an image. A 4x4 image will have 16 pixels - if you delete one your image viewing app will refuse to load it saying it is corrupted. Maybe you want to make it transparent? Or black? If there were pixels missing, all the other pixels would shuffle together to fill the gap and the image would be distorted - previously straight lines not straight etc,

Comment: @ Mark Setchell why i cant ?if i use some shp to clipping image is the some result but i want to clipping from the value price

Comment: You can delete pixels, but you can mask pixels, do you mean mask the pixels?

Comment: mask or how to can create new raster with some class using raster calculation expressions(i update my question)

Comment: `np.delete` is for deleting (in the 2D case) rows and columns, As everyone else has said, it doesn't mean anything to delete a single pixel. If you delete a pixel, what do you expect to see where that pixel was when you display the image?

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"i cant to complete"_?

Comment: ok then i must to create new raster calculation with one or more class from original raster

Comment: how can i use mask ?if  i use this command `inputr=input.tif` 
                                                                       `calc=inputr>3`
                                                                       `outp=path/ +calc_+'.tif'`
that method is wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Rasters are 2-D arrays of values, with each value being stored in a pixel (which stands for picture element). Each pixel must contain some information. It is not possible to delete or remove pixels from the array because rasters are usually encoded as a simple 1-dimensional string of bits. Metadata commonly helps explain where line breaks are and the length of the bitstring, so that the 1-D bitstring can be understood as a 2-D array. If you "remove" a pixel, then you break the raster. The 2-D grid is no longer valid.

Of course, there are many instances where you do want to effectively discard or clean the raster of data. Such an example might be to remove pixels that cover land from a raster of sea-surface temperatures. To accomplish this goal, many geospatial raster formats hold metadata describing what are called NoData values. Pixels containing a NoData value are **interpreted** as not existing. Recall that in a raster, each pixel must contain some information. The NoData paradigm allows the structure and format of rasters to be met, while also giving a way to **mask** pixels from being displayed or analyzed. There is still data (bits, 1s and 0s) at the masked pixels, but it only serves to identify the pixel as invalid.

With this in mind, here is an example using `gdal` which will mask values in the range of 0-100 so they are NoData, and "do not exist". The NoData value will be specified as 0.

```
from osgeo import gdal

# open dataset to read, and get a numpy array
ds = gdal.Open("raster3.tif", 'r')
myarray = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
# modify numpy array to mask values
myarray[myarray <= 100] = 0

# open output dataset, which is a copy of original
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds_out = driver.CreateCopy("raster3_with_nodata.tif", ds)
# write the modified array to the raster
ds_out.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(myarray)
# set the NoData metadata flag
ds_out.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(0)
# clear the buffer, and ensure file is written
ds_out.FlushCache()
```

Comment: i thing so work fine thank you very much this is a good course,i have queston in the ine `myarray[myarray <= 100] = 0` can to import more complex range like this `50 < myarray[myarray <= 100] = 0 ` ? you say NoData value will be 0,maybe is wrong ?maybe bette value like -99999 ?

Comment: @chrischris: You can choose any value you like as as your NoData value. Just make sure it's the same thing as what you pass to `SetNoDataValue`. As for your other question, you're looking for `myarray[(50 < myarray) &   (myarray <= 100)] = 0`

Answer (score 1):

I want to contribute with an example for landsat data.
In this qick guide, you will be able to exclude Landsat cloud pixels.
Landsat offers the Quality Assessment Band (BQA), which includes int32 values (classes) regarding natural features such as Clouds, Rocks, Ice, Water, Cloud Shadow etc.

We will use the BQA to clip the cloud pixels in the other bands.

```py
# Import Packages
import rasterio as rio
import earthpy.plot as ep
from matplotlib import pyplot
import rioxarray as rxr
from numpy import ma

# Open the Landsat Band 3
Landsat_Image = rxr.open_rasterio(r"C:\...\LC08_L1TP_223075_20210311_20210317_01_T1_B3.tif")

# Open the Quality Assessment Band 
BQA = rxr.open_rasterio(r"C:\...\LC08_L1TP_223075_20210311_20210317_01_T1_BQA.tif").squeeze()

# Create a list with the QA values that represent cloud, cloud_shadow, etc.
Cloud_Values = [6816, 6848, 6896, 7072]

# Mask the data using the pixel QA layer
landsat_masked = Landsat_Image.where(~BQA.isin(Cloud_Values))
landsat_masked

# Plot the masked data
landsat_masked_plot = ma.masked_array(landsat_masked.values,landsat_masked.isnull())

# Plot
ep.plot_rgb(landsat_masked_plot, rgb=[2, 1, 0], title = "Masked Data")
plt.show()
###############################################################################
# Export the masked Landsat Scenes to Directory "Masked_Bands_QA"
out_img = landsat_masked
out_img.shape
out_transform = landsat_masked.rio.transform()

# Get a Band of the same Scene for reference
rastDat = rio.open(r"C:\Dados_Espaciais\NDVI_Usinas\Adeco\Indices\Imagens\LC08_L1TP_223075_20210311_20210317_01_T1\LC08_L1TP_223075_20210311_20210317_01_T1_B3.tif")


#copying metadata from original raster
out_meta = rastDat.meta.copy()

#amending original metadata
out_meta.update({'nodata': 0,
                 'height' : out_img.shape[1],
                 'width' : out_img.shape[2],
                 'transform' : out_transform}) 

# writing and then re-reading the output data to see if it looks good
for i in range(out_img.shape[0]):
    with rio.open(rf"C:\Dados_Espaciais\DSM\Bare_Soil_Landsat\Teste_{i+1}_masked.tif",'w',**out_meta) as dst:
        dst.write(out_img[i,:,:],1)
```

This way you tell the program:
Check the areas in BQA with these "Cloud_Values" and exclude these areas, but in the landsat image that I provided.
I hope it works.